# find the sum of $n$ terms of the series $1+2(1-a) +3(1-a)(1-2a)+\cdots \cdots +k(1-a)(1-2a)\cdots\{1-(k-1)a\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

find the sum of $n$ terms of the series

$1+2(1-a) +3(1-a)(1-2a)+\cdots \cdots +k(1-a)(1-2a)\cdots\{1-(k-1)a\}$

wan,t be able to go ahead, could some help me with this, thanks

Comment: Considering $x_n=1-na$, this is $$a^{-1}\left(1-x_1+x_1(1-x_2)+\cdots+(1-x_k)x_1\cdots x_{k-1}\right)$$ which, by concatenation, is also $$a^{-1}\left(1-x_1\cdots x_{k-1}x_k\right)=a^{-1}\left(1-\prod_{n=1}^k(1-na)\right)$$

Comment: thanks did for nice explanation.